# Laravel eloquent - Doctrine features equivalent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, doctrine-orm

Coming from a long Symfony-Doctrine background, I have started learning Laravel 8.

One of my first discovery was that migration needed to be manually created after using `make:migration` (from what I understood thus far) in both Models and Migration.

Symfony, with Doctrine, allowed a bunch of automatisation, and I only needed to create the field or relation from the Model (php annotation or yaml) - before launching `doctrine:schema:validate` and `make:migration`
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#migrations-adding-more-fields.
Let 'say I create a Post and Comment entity, with a One-To-Many relationship.
If I define the relation in the php classes

```
class Comment extends Model
{

    /**
     * Get the Post owning this comment
     */
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
}
```

Post class

```
class Post extends Model
{    
    /**
     * Get the comments for the blog post.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}
```

Is possible to generate the migration scripts that would update the database and create these relation ship ? Or will I have to rewrite it twice (once in the PHP class with hasMany/BelongsTo then again in the Migtration file ? 
Not having a central file to map/read a model (which linkied php and database) seems weird to me now.
I've only started but the documentation does not seems to mention anything equivalent

**Edit** : for more clarity : I'm asking if there are equivalent of Generating migration code/script from models (or a central mapping file : yaml or annotation ) without having to write fields to both migration and models ( in $fillable or other fields...)

**Edit 2** Closest thing I could find is this
https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended
Another use case where this is cumbersome : many-to-many migrations
Having to manually write that third middle table from scratch is really something I wish was made automatically.

Comment: That's what I don't like about Laravel migrations. The package [`barryvdh/laravel-migration-generator`](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-migration-generator) might give you a similar experience.

Comment: In Laravel, is the inverse of Doctrine. Eloquent models do not have to be "married" with its migration, making it super simple to start using your models directly, and giving you the flexibility on creating your migration.

Using external packages to infer the migration can be useful at first, but looses utility in the long term. The best advice is to get use to set your migrations and models and enjoy the magical beauty of Eloquent in other contexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In laravel framework despite other famous fameworks like symfony or python django, you're responsible for making database migration files. By this way, you are free to customize your database schema and add any database constrains like (unique constrain, relation constrains and etc.). Also you can add any raw sql using `\DB::unprepared();` in your migration files.

I can tell you that it is normal to be a little confuse about this flow, because you've used to this kind of automation in other frameworks like I did, but beilieve me, you get to used to this flow.

By the way, there are some packages out there that do this automation (create migration files according to model) for you.

Comment: I might get used but I'm surprised : I'd rather spend time writing business logic than rewriting twice the field logics. And it's error prone (Im light headed ) since I do it by hand.
And having to double check the validity of my fields by hand is cumbersome :|

Comment: Yes, it's a bit annoying at first. But I don't recommend you to do this by an external package, it'll become buggy in the long run.

Comment: I definitly don't want to use an external package. That's why I was always pleased with Doctrine.

Comment: Unlike doctrine, Laravel migrations useful for creating your database logic in a generic way separated from your models, so in your server you can change from MariaDB to SQL Server, for example, without touching your app logic (models). So, instead of spend time writing Doctrine dockblocks in your models specific for your database manager and repositories for standard operations, you can use the magic of Eloquent.  That's one thing I miss from Laravel when I have to use Doctrine in Symfony.

Answer (score -2):

For creating a migration you need to run command

```
php artisan make:migration migration_name
```

And for creating a model you need to run command

```
php artisan make:model table_name
```

Refer to this link
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#generating-model-classes

By creating a model you create a table, where you can define the columns types and different properties and define the relationship with other tables.
By creating a migration file you can define the table columns and the constraints.

Comment: Question is not about how to create migration file for a model, it is asking for a way to automatically fill migration file according to a model fields.

Comment: So there is no equivalent ? I will have to write all by hand ? 
This isn't  deal-breaker or anything but I'm surprised such a featre is not present. it's kinda cumbersome, time-consuming and error-prone.

Comment: When you run the migration command it will generate a base structure and nothing else. By using external packages you can generate migration as per the model. But if you do not want to use the external packages then you will have to write it yourself.
By running the command given above it will generate the base structure so you will have to just add the columns and its definition.